# What is a better way to store both shortest path and its length in a Maze?

Tags: c++, queue, breadth-first-search, maze

I am using Lee's algorithm to find the shortest path inside a maze.

The maze consists of 0s and 1s. A cell with value 1 represents an empty space one can go to, a cell with value 0 is an obstacle one cannot pass.

However, by doing the `q.pop()` part inside the `while(!q.isEmpty())` loop, I am loosing my "nodes"(I have implemented a strucutre `pozitie_plan` that stores the index of the row, the index of the column and the distance between an arbitrary-chosen point in a matrix and itself). These "nodes" could be part of the path that I want to output in the end. Yet, I think I should not be altering that part.

I am restricted to use the Queue on DLLA (Dynamic Linked List on Array). I have implemented my own. If needed, I will add its implementation, too.

The way I am finding the path is by determining the shortest length using Lee's algorithm and leaving a trace on an auxiliary matrix, the value in an (i, j) cell representing the distance from the source to that cell.

Finally, I am tracing back a path(there could be more than one, I believe) starting from the exit of the maze (provided the exit has been found) to the starting position, by searching for those cells that have the value equal to: the value in the current cell - 1.

I am keeping these `pozitie_plan` nodes in a queue, then reverting the queue in the end and outputing the final result.

I feel this could be done better. But how ?

Here is my code. If asked for, I could edit the post and change the code I posted to a version that has some `cout`s and more commentaries and / or the implementation for the Queue.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Queue.h"
#include "ShortTest.h"
#include "ExtendedTest.h"

#define Nmax 25

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::swap;

#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;


template<typename T>
void citeste_mat(ifstream &input_stream, T mat[][Nmax], int &n, int &m)
{
    input_stream >> n >> m; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            input_stream >> mat[i][j];
}

void citeste_poz_start(ifstream &input_stream, pozitie_plan &p)
{
    input_stream >> p.i >> p.j;
    p.dist = 0;
    p.i--; p.j--;               // utilizatorul vede in indexare de la 1, dar eu am implementat in indexare de la 0!
}

template<typename V>
void citeste_date(ifstream &input_file, V mat[][Nmax], int &n, int &m, pozitie_plan &p)
{
    citeste_mat<V>(input_file, mat, n, m);
    citeste_poz_start(input_file, p);
}

template<typename U> // ar fi fost problema daca puneam aici tot "T" in loc de "U" ?
void afis_mat(U mat[][Nmax], int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

bool valid_pozitie( int i, int j, int n, int m)
{
    return 0 <= i && i < n && 0 <= j && j < m;
}

template<typename T>
bool obstacol(T mat[][Nmax], pozitie_plan p)
{
    return mat[p.i][p.j] == 0;
}

template<typename T>
bool valid_nevizitat(T aux[][Nmax], pozitie_plan p)
{
    return aux[p.i][p.j] == false;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
bool valid(T mat[][Nmax], U aux[][Nmax], pozitie_plan p, int n, int m)
{
    return valid_pozitie(p.i, p.j, n, m) && !obstacol<T>(mat, p) && valid_nevizitat<U>(aux, p);
}

// e un pic "overhead" sa am toate functiile astea de valid, stiu; dar parca imi place sa am totul cat se poate de fragmentat

bool pe_contur(pozitie_plan p, int n, int m)
{
    // return p.i == 0 || p.j == 0 || p.i == n - 1 || p.j == m - 1;
    return p.i * p.j == 0 || p.i == n-1 || p.j == m-1;
}

template<typename T>
bool solution(T mat[][Nmax], pozitie_plan p , int n, int m)
{
    return !obstacol(mat, p) && pe_contur(p, n, m);
}


template<typename T>
pozitie_plan gaseste_cale(T mat[][Nmax], int n, int m, pozitie_plan ps)
{
    // voi pastra integritatea matricii ( mat nu va fi modificata )

    const int dx[] = { -1, 0, 1, 0 };
    const int dy[] = { 0, 1, 0, -1};

    bool visited[Nmax][Nmax] = { false };

    visited[ps.i][ps.j] = true;             // marchez pozitia de start ca vizitata 

    Queue q;
    q.push(ps);                             // bag in coada pozitia de start

    pozitie_plan current_pos;
    int row, column, distance;

    while (!q.isEmpty())
    // cat timp exista in coada pozitii pentru care trebuie verificati vecinii (daca vecinii sunt iesire sau nu)
    {
        current_pos = q.top();
        if (solution<int>(mat, current_pos, n, m))
        {
            return current_pos; // voi returna prima solutie gasita, care garantat va fi cea mai scurta (BFS)
        }

        q.pop();        // stocand head ul in `current_pos` pot spune ca am tratat ce aveam in head, asa cu fac pop

        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            row = current_pos.i + dx[k];
            column = current_pos.j + dy[k];
            distance = current_pos.dist + 1;

            pozitie_plan vecin{ row, column, distance };

            if (valid<int,bool>(mat, visited, vecin, n, m))

            {
                mat[row][column] = distance;
                visited[row][column] = true;
                q.push(vecin);
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL_POZITIE_PLAN;
}

void reconstruct_path(int mat[][Nmax], int n, int m, pozitie_plan end, pozitie_plan begin, Queue& q)
{
    const int dx[] = { -1, 0, 1, 0 };
    const int dy[] = { 0, 1, 0, -1 };

    q.push(end);

    pozitie_plan current_pos = end;
    int row, column, distance;
    int len = current_pos.dist;
    while(len != 1)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            row = current_pos.i + dx[k];
            column = current_pos.j + dy[k];
            distance = mat[row][column];
            if (valid_pozitie(row, column, n, m)
                && distance == len - 1)
            {
                pozitie_plan new_pos = pozitie_plan{ row, column, distance };
                q.push(new_pos);
                current_pos = new_pos;
                break;
            }
        }
        len--;
    }
    q.push(begin);
}


void reverse_queue(Queue& q, const int len)
{
    pozitie_plan *aux = new pozitie_plan[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        aux[i] = q.pop();

    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        swap(aux[i], aux[len - 1 - i]);

    for (int i = 0; i <len ; i++)
        q.push(aux[i]);
}


int main()
{

    int mat[Nmax][Nmax] = { 0 };
    int n, m;
    pozitie_plan pozitie_start;

    ifstream input_file;
    input_file.open("input.txt", ios::in);
    citeste_date<int>(input_file, mat, n, m, pozitie_start);        
    input_file.close();

    afis_mat<int>(mat, n, m);

    // pana aici citesc datele de intrare

    pozitie_plan end = gaseste_cale<int>(mat, n, m, pozitie_start); // presupun ca utilizatorul numara liniile & coloanele de la 1
    if (end == NULL_POZITIE_PLAN) 
    {
        cout << "NO SOLUTION FOUND!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        // Queue cale = reconstruct_path(mat, n, m, end);
        Queue cale;
        reconstruct_path(mat, n, m, end, pozitie_start, cale);
        reverse_queue(cale, end.dist + 1);  
        cout << "The shortest path (length = " << end.dist << " not including the starting position) to be followed in the given matrix (above) is:\n";
        cale.toString();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example**

**input.txt**

```
18 20
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
17 3
```

**console output**

```
The shortest path...// everything is ok, the path is ok
```

Comment: You can use Dijkstra's algorithm provided there are no negative cost cycles in the matrix. To calculate the shortest path, for each vertex save it's parent vertex which is the vertex which leads to the current vertex in the Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @lucieon Thank you for commenting and for the idea!

Comment: The way you describe doing it -- use Lee's algorithm with an aux matrix to store the visited marks and distances, tracing back into a queue -- sound fine, but the code looks quite long for that.

Comment: @MattTimmermans hello! and thank you for your response!